# Is it possible to use TypeScripts decorator to validate value of method parameters?

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I try to follow this manual [TypeScript parameter decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) but struggle to get it out is it possible to create the decorator to validate the method parameter as following:

```
class World{
   constructor(){
   }

   sayHelloTo(@checkIfNameBeginsWithCapital name: string){
      console.log("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

If I understood correctly it can be achieved by creating two decorators, as following:

```
class World{
   constructor(){
   }

   @validate
   sayHelloTo(@nameBeginWithCapital name: string){
      console.log("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

`@nameBeginWithCapital` will define metadata on a parameter and `@validate` will look for the parameter with such metadata and perform actual validation, am I right?

The question do I understand correctly and if not, can `@checkIfNameBeginsWithCapital` be created to perform this task without additional decorators within current TS limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @nameBeginWithCapital will define metadata on a parameter and @validate will look for the parameter with such metadata and perform actual validation, am I right?

Exactly. Parameter Decorators can only be used to add metadata. The "heavy lifting" needs to be done via a method decorator, exactly as you described. A good example and an explanation can be found in the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators) (as you already found and which is the official source), which showcases what you are trying to achieve but with a `required` validation instead.

I modified the example from the handbook to suit your case and got it working on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-drudj1?file=index.ts).

Comment: Thank you very much!